# Draw a circle's sector using its borders

Tags: css, css-shapes

As shown below:

[image]

I want to draw a sector of a circle using borders only in order to make something like a chart, but if it's possible I don't want to use any plugins.

```css
    .circle {
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 4px solid #0c8a98;
      border-radius: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: [This](http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/2011/how-to-create-pie-charts-with-css3/) can help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the article show how to draw a chart using background-color.
I want to make it using borders only.

Comment: Why are you so intent on doing it with borders only? It is virtually impossible to do this with borders because (a) normal borders can't produce gradients (b) `border-image` which can produce gradients will not produce circle (it won't be clipped).

Comment: @Harry I think you're right, I tried it several times with several techniques.
could it be possible using SVG ?

Comment: @user3638463: Yes, this should be possible using SVG or Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Do this. The border sides need to added individually.

```
.circle {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: transparent;
 border-top: none;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #0c8a98;
 border-left: 4px solid #0c8a98;
 border-right: 4px solid #0c8a98;
 border-radius: 100%;
}

<div class="circle"></div>
```